# How to reach struct sk_buff members?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to modify the source IP of all packets outcoming from the machine to something I specify in this Kernel Module, but everytime I try to access **nh.iph->saddr** I get an error in *compile* time that says **Struct sk_buff has no member named nh**

What am I doing wrong here?
Have I missed some header or something??

```
#include <linux/module.h>       
#include <linux/kernel.h>       
#include <linux/init.h>         

#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>

#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>                  /* For IP header */

#include <linux/inet.h> /* For in_aton(); htonl(); and other related Network utility functions */ 


static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;


unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum,
                       struct sk_buff **skb,
                       const struct net_device *in,
                       const struct net_device *out,
                       int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{
    struct sk_buff *sb = *skb;
    struct in_addr masterIP;

    masterIP.s_addr = htonl (in_aton("192.168.1.10")); 
    sb->nh.iph->saddr = masterIP.s_addr;
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

Note that I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64 bits 
Kernel 2.6.32-33

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your kernel version the `struct sk_buff` has changed. It no longer has those members. To access the ip header you should try:

```
#include <linux/ip.h>

struct iphdr* iph = ip_hdr(skb);
```

Then just use the `iph` variable to change the addresses, something like:

```
iph->saddr = ....
iph->daddr = ....
```

Also, don't forget that you might need to recalculate `ip` and possible transport packets checksums.

Comment: Thanks a lot =D Solved ^^
EDIT: The IP checksum, okay...
But why the Transport packet checksums too?

Comment: For example, UDP checksum accounts for the so called ``ip pseudo header``, which means that UDP checksum uses some fields of the IP header, such as the source and destination addresses. I don't quite remember, but I think TCP also does this.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the definition of struck sk_buff in 'include/linux/skbuff.h'.

It does not have an nh field, which explains the compilation errors you're seeing. It does have a 'network_header' field, which is probably what you're looking for.